# POST multipart/form-data buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, изображения, buffer, multipart

```
    const request = require('request');
        let base64 = "base64 ....";
                    let buff = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');
                    const options = {
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "http://192.168.88.21",
                        port: 9001,
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                        },
                        formData : {
                            value: buff.buffer,
                            options: {
                                filename: 'pic.jpeg'
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    request(options, function (err, res, body) {
                        if(err) console.log(err);
                        console.log(body);
                    });
```

Я пытаюсь отправить на свой сервер картинку из памяти, получаю ошибку при сборке -
"source.on('error', function() {});"

Подскажите, как правильно отправить картинку из памяти через **multipart/form-data**

Comment: В вашем коде не хватает собственно отправки

Comment: Что такое request?

Comment: спасибо. исправил. я не заметил при копировании.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads В документации formData это отдельный аргумент, а не часть options.

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за ссылку , я вынес отдельно. Я всё равно получаю эту ошибку. Мне кажется я не умею правильно работать с Buffer.  Как правильно в  const formData , my_buffer присвоить let buff = new Buffer(base64, 'base64'); ?

Comment: Что за `buff.buffer`? `buff` это уже Buffer.

Comment: Я не уверен, но вроде как нужно отравлять `new Blob(buff.buffer, {type: 'image/jpg'})`, a не просто `buff.buffer` .